# OneDrive Custom Metadata on Files

Tags: onedrive

I would like to store some additional metadata with documents that I am uploading to OneDrive (Business) using the OneDrive API, for example type of document, some additional information to search on , ...

Does anyone know if this is possible at this time? I noticed the following URL
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/misc/custom-metadata.md
But only support for OneDrive Personal??

To create a new facet, the OneDrive team needs to be informed via mail ? 
Before a new custom facet can be used, you need to define its schema and register it with OneDrive. To register your custom facet, contact OneDrive Facet Registration and provide your client_id and schema definition JSON.

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: Anyone any feedback?

Comment: Hi Jens, did you find any solution for this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reviving a post a bit later because my search found this question.  I am going through custom facet registration at present.  It is necessary to email the OneDrive team, and as part of that I needed to confirm in my reply that this was indeed only for OneDrive personal, not business / Sharepoint.

The e-mail link is shown in the OneDrive dev docs:
https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/custom-metadata.htm

Comment: They're yet to reply my registration request.